# Issue in Laravel Files Paths while moved to IIS

Tags: php, iis, laravel, laravel-routing

My files will load the .css , .js files in the laravel way

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/style.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/jquery.js') }}
```

So when ever i access the file, by `mydomain.com/public` it takes the path as

```
mydomain.com/public/assets/css/style.css
mydomain.com/public/assets/js/jquery.js
```

As i moved it to IIS Hosting I need to access my files only by

```
mydomain.com/public/index.php
```

**(Is there a way to fix it in IIS Server or ...)**

While i tryto access the file by giving `mydomain.com/public/index.php` It takes the path as

```
mydomain.com/public/index.php/assets/css/style.css
mydomain.com/public/index.php/assets/js/jquery.js
```

Which makes 404 Error for those .css and .js files.

**How can i fix this ?**

Comment: Did you set the public folder in virtual host ? Do you still have .htaccess in your public folder ?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/style.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/jquery.js') }}
```

Make sure you delete the views in the Storage Folder

If you use Artisian

```
$ php artisan cache:clear
```

Else in Direct Just go to `app->storage->views` and remove all the files in the Views.

Also Check the `app->storage->logs->laravel.log` for the Error Log